# Erlang RabbitMQ client example not working

Tags: erlang, websocket, rabbitmq, cowboy

Erlang RabbitMQ Client not working...(http://www.rabbitmq.com/erlang-client-user-guide.html)

Somehow my RabbitMQ Erlang client is not working.. It gives "can't find amqp_client.hrl" error when i try to compile it using

```
ERL_LIBS=deps erlc -o ebin amqp_example.erl
```

Here are the steps I have taken.

1. Created module amqp_example.erl
2. Created deps folder
3. Put rabbit-common and amqp_client inside deps folder
4. Compiled using  ERL_LIBS=deps erlc -o ebin amqp_example.erl

Can anyone let me know what I am missing. BTW I am very new to erlang.

Also, i want to create a application which can connect using websocket to ERlang (Preferably Cowboy) and from there I can connect to rabbitMQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it worked. It required rabbitmq server which was not compiled properly.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone let me know what I am missing.

The compiler error indicates that `erlc` is unable to locate the `amqp_client.hrl` header file. Post some example code detailing how you're including the header file. Normally you would use `include_lib("amqp_client.hrl").` if you're telling the compiler about the location of the amqp_client application by setting the `ERL_LIBS` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. Thats exactly what i am doing including file using -include_lib("amqp_client.hrl").

Comment: Example code is located at:-  https://www.rabbitmq.com/erlang-client-user-guide.html